# Vue.js shorthand colon is removed by Visual Studio formatting

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, code-formatting

I develop in vue.js using Visual Studio. I have code that uses the colon ":" instead of v-bind.
If I use the formatting option of Visual Studio (ctrl+k,ctrl+d), the colon is removed.

sample :

in index.html

```
<mycomponent :prop1="value"></mycomponent>
```

after formatting

```
<mycomponent prop1="value"></mycomponent>
```

Is there a way to fix the formatting and keep the colon?

---

from : [vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)

```
<!-- full syntax -->
<a v-bind:href="url"> ... </a>
<!-- shorthand -->
<a :href="url"> ... </a>
```